# page to page swipe on IOS application for the calabash-ios

Tags: cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

Does anyone know how to define the swipe of a UIPageControl in an iOS application for the calabash-ios because I cannot move the Page for swiping when I used this predefined steps

Then /^I swipe right "([^\"]*)"$/ do |thisispage2| swipe :right, :query => "UIPageControl:'#{thisispage2}'",force: :strong 
end

[how to swipe from page to page on an iOS pagination view using calabash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844065/how-to-swipe-from-page-to-page-on-an-ios-pagination-view-using-calabash/33665449#33665449)

Thanks

Regards

Carlo

Answer (score 0):

You can use UI automation for this.
In your step definition write something like:

```
uia("UIATarget.localTarget().dragFromToForDuration({x:'ORIGIN_X', y:'ORIGIN_Y'}, {x:'TARGET_X', y:'TARGET_Y'}, DURATION)")
```

This piece of code drag from 1 point, to another over a given duration. Make sure all origin and target points are within the screen bounds, otherwise UIAutomation will throw an exception.

Even better would be if you make it into a function:

```
def custom_drag(x_origin, y_origin, x_target, y_target, duration)
  uia("UIATarget.localTarget().dragFromToForDuration({x:'#{x_origin.to_i}', y:'#{y_origin.to_i}'}, {x:'#{x_target.to_i}', y:'#{y_target.to_i}'}, #{duration.to_i})")
end
```